# assembler 8086 need help on clearing out a problem

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I could use your help on a program that I'm writing as my school project. It has to open a file that contains about 3000 lines which contains of five fields that are separated by ";". First field is with letters (and it can be max 10 chars), other fields are numbers in range from -100 to 100. It should look something like that:

> DSGHAA;12;24;55;-84

The assignment is that I have to open file that contains those lines, and check if line meets some requirements and if it meets them, write that line to another file, that will be created.
Requirements that are needed to be met:
1. It has to have two "A" letters in first field (not more, not less)(max 10 characters);
2. Second and third fields has positive numbers;
3. Fourth and fifth fields has to divide from 11;
Here's a part of my code:

```
-----------------Reading characters--------------------
.beginning
    inc di
    mov bx, [bp]              
    mov cx, 1
    mov dx, character
    mov ah, 0x3F
    int 0x21
    mov cl, [character]
    jnc .tikrinimas
    macPutString 'Error reading file', crlf, '$'

---------Checking if it isn't end of reading file------ 

.startChecking
    cmp ax, 0
    jne .ifLineEnd
    jmp .closing

---------Checking if it is the end of line-------------
.ifLineEnds
    cmp cl, 0x0A
    je .splitLine
    mov [line+di], cl
    jmp .beginning

---------Startting to split my line into "fields"------ 
.splitLine
    mov [line+di], cl
    mov si, 0
    mov di, 0
    .firstField
        mov al, byte [line+di]
        mov byte [field1+si], al
        cmp byte [line+di], ';'
        je .splitLine2
        inc di
        inc si
        loop .firstField

.splitLine2
    mov si, 0
    inc di
    .secondField
        mov al, byte [line+di]
        mov byte [field2+si], al
        cmp byte [line+di], ';'
        je .splitLine3
        inc di
        inc si
        loop .secondField

.splitLine3
    mov si, 0
    inc di
    .thirdField
        mov al, byte [line+di]
        mov byte [field3+si], al
        cmp byte [line+di], ';'
        je .splitLine4
        inc di
        inc si
        loop .thirdField

.splitLine4
    mov si, 0
    inc di
    .fourthField
        mov al, byte [line+di]
        mov byte [field4+si], al
        cmp byte [line+di], ';'
        je .splitLine5
        inc di
        inc si
        loop .fourthField

.splitLine5
    mov si, 0
    inc di
    .fifthField
        mov al, byte [line+di]
        mov byte [field5+si], al
        cmp byte [line+di], ';'
        je .howManyA               <----This is where I have a problem..
        inc di
        inc si
        loop .fifthField

-------counting how many "A" are in first field-------  
.howManyA
    mov si, 0
    mov ch, 0
    .check
        cmp byte [field1+si], ';'
        je .numberA
        cmp byte [field1+si], 'A'
        jne .next
        inc ch
        inc si
        jmp .check
        .next
            inc si
            jmp .check

    .numberA
        cmp ch, 2
        je .isFirstPositive
        jmp .toBeginning

--------checking if first number is positive----------      
.isFirstPositive
    mov ch, byte [field2]
    cmp ch, 0x2D
    jne .isSecondPositive
    jmp .toBeginning

--------checking if second number is positive---------      
.isSecondPositive
    mov ch, byte [field3]
    cmp ch, 0xD2
    jmp .toBeginning

--------checking if third number divides from 11------  
.firstDivide
    mov ah, byte [field4]
    cmp ax, 0
    je .toBeginning
    cmp ah, 0xD2
    je .numbers
       .numbers
            mov ah, byte [laukas4+01]
            mov al, byte [laukas4+02]
    cmp ah, al
    je .secondDivide
    jmp .toBeginning

------checking if fourth number divides from 11------
.secondBeggining
    mov ah, [field5+00]
    cmp ax, 0
    je .toBeginning
    cmp ah, 0xD2
    je .numbers2
        .numbers2
            mov ah, byte [field5+01]
            mov al, byte [field5+02]
    cmp ah, al
    je .writeToFile
    jmp .toBeginning

-----------jumping to beginning to read another line---------       
.toBeginning
    mov di, -1
    jmp .beginning


---------------data----------------------------------
section .data

character: times 1 db 00
line: times 32 db 00
field1: times 11 db 00
field2: times 5 db 00
field3: times 5 db 00
field4: times 5 db 00
field5: times 5 db 00
```

I've omitted code parts where is opening, creating, writing and closing files. That works. 
I've showed on my code where is a problem and I can't determine why..
I have a test file

> input.txt that contains this line "AA;12;15;55;-77

Now, when I debug my program, everything works perfectly until it reaches first "7". Program compares "7" (ASCII 37) with ";" (ASCII 3B) and jumps to ".howManyA". I can't figure out why it does that and what to look for..
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That should not happen. Verify you are using your debugger correctly and indeed `al` equals `'7'` at that point. I find it more likely that you don't understand how `loop` works because you don't set `cx` to a sensible counter value and it's actually that's falling through into `howManyA` not the `je`. I guess you just want `jmp` instead of **all** your `loop` instructions.

Comment: I tested it and I can confirm the assumption of @Jester. It **is** the `loop` that doesn't jump because `CX` reaches 0.

Comment: Jester, thank you a lot, you're right, problem was in loop, i've debugged my code and problem was in loop and in CX register. changed all loops in jmp and work like a charm. Thank you again